# Apache 2 Debian SSL Certification not exist

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl

I'm not really good with Apache and that is the reason why I'm writing to you. I have installed a web server in SSL following some indication from the software vendor.

When I restart the service I get this error

```
root@doc1:~# service apache2 restart
[FAIL] Restarting web server: apache2 failed!
[warn] The apache2 configtest failed. ... (warning).
Output of config test was:
AH00526: Syntax error on line 49 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/default-ssl.conf:
SSLCertificateFile: file '/etc/ssl/certs/wildcard.skylable.com.pem' does not exist or is empty
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

I check the path and I don't have the `wildcard.skylable.com.pem` file
I think that I have overwritten something during the installation. Do you know how can I restore it?

Comment: A few questions: 1.) How did you configure the server to use an SSL certificate? (did you modify files manually yourself or push a button on a site) 2.) Did the vendor provide you the SSL certificate? 3.) What does `updatedb && locate wildcard.skylable.com.pem` return?

Comment: Hi Paul, Thanks for the reply. The certificate *SHOULD* be installed automatically but seems not.
That is the output of the command required

root@doc1:~# updatedb && locate wildcard.skylable.com.pem
root@doc1:~#

Comment: What does `updatedb && locate wildcard.skylable.com.pem` display?